# gcc-12 error when installing R packages (e.g. DESeq2)

Tags: r, gcc

The problem arose when I tried installing DESeq2.

Running: `BiocManager::install("DESeq2")` produced

```
Installing package(s) 'DESeq2'
also installing the dependencies 'sys', 'fastmap', 'askpass',
```

Download was fine, then this error occured for every single package and dependency:

```
* installing *source* package 'sys' ...
** package 'sys' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc-12 -I"/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/libtirpc/include/tirpc -I/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gettext/include -I/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/readline/include -I/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/xz/include -I/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/include   -fpic  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c exec.c -o exec.o
/bin/bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-12: Bad address
make: *** [/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:169: exec.o] Error 126
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'sys'
* removing '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/sys'
```

So the error seems to be with the GCC-12, because of this line:

```
/bin/bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-12: Bad address
```

Running `gcc --version` produces:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Running `gcc-12 --version` produces:

```
-bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc-12: Bad address
```

It seems to be [a recent problem](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/115895) following `homebrew upgrade` but I am running the latest WSL Kernel version (Kernel version: 5.10.102.1).

Lastly, running `brew postinstall gcc` produces:

```
==> Postinstalling gcc
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall gcc
```

I ran `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and got

```
build-essential is already the newest version (12.8ubuntu1.1).
```

Running `brew reinstall gcc` produces:

```
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/gcc/manifests/12.2.0-2
Already downloaded: /home/osekulovic/.cache/Homebrew/downloads/a4a4a48db6f1c5ebc47c0929825c735a0c4837922713f6773cb4fbec928e5a8f--gcc-12.2.0-2.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/gcc/blobs/sha256:d2080ede63b45e711bbb05c474af6affe3edc255fecf81009a85e23429b509e2
Already downloaded: /home/osekulovic/.cache/Homebrew/downloads/ab6926110713961da39411864073329dbfc562bde4cdad0f4f3f17fe1b4640cd--gcc--12.2.0.x86_64_linux.bottle.2.tar.gz
==> Reinstalling gcc
==> Pouring gcc--12.2.0.x86_64_linux.bottle.2.tar.gz
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall gcc
==> Summary
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0: 1,623 files, 306.6MB
==> Running `brew cleanup gcc`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

Help highly appreaciated!

TP

Comment: Please try `brew reinstall gcc` and if there are any errors/warnings, please edit your post and include the errors/warnings verbatim. You may need to install build essentials (`sudo apt-get install build-essential`) before gcc will build correctly (per https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core/issues/13596)

Comment: Have you tried `brew reinstall gcc-12`?

Comment: There is a lot of discussion regarding this problem at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/115895; perhaps one of the solutions there will solve the issue?